# Dynamically add textbox in HTML Page through Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want dynamically add text-box in html page when user is press a button. and after that i want to get the respective field value or all field value.

I tried doing `ng-repeat` but it will not work. can anyone tell me how i will achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I would indeed use ng-repeat, and just push a new object onto the array. Maybe something like this?

```
<button ng-click="textFields.push("")">Add</button>
<textarea ng-repeat="val in textFields" ng-model="val"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well there are a few things you could try. One of them is loading a hidden div when clicked on the button. The hidden div contains the text box.
Like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     $("#hiddendiv").hide();
     $("#button").click(function(){
     $("#zmedia").show();
}};
```

And in your html form you just add a div that contains a textbox and the id of the dive should be "hiddendiv".  The downside is that once the hidden div is loaded, it cant be removed. There are other scripts that are a lot more sophisticated, check these links out:

- https://github.com/wam/jquery-addable
- http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/

Comment: Since OP is using AngularJS, there's no reason to assume they use jQuery (usually they don't try to go together)

Comment: i want this through angular JS. no jquery Avuerro

Comment: im sorry, was hasty and overlooked the angular JS part. I cant help you with that, good luck finding a solution !